# DotNetNuke 6 - RadEditor - How do I change the dimensions of the default HTML Module Editor?

Tags: dotnetnuke

A regression in DotNetNuke 6 is that, by default, the editor appears in an in-page popup that uses a very limited portion of the screen.

While the editor does include the ability to go "full screen", this is not the default.

Is there a setting some place that I can adjust to cause it to always start full screen, or at least start out larger so that I don't have to scroll down to hit the save button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for getting rid of this limited in-screen popup is to disable popups site-wide in the site settings (admin menu).

[image]

This will cause a full page load when the `edit content` button is clicked. The editing will be perform on a self-contained page. Clicking save will return the editor back to the page whose module is being edited.

**Warning** - Using this option will cause bulleted lists to not display as bulleted lists in design view within the default html editor